# Visual Studio Click Once deployment problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have a visual studio click once deployment.  It's upgraded from VS 2008.  The part that i'm having a problem with is the Prerequisites. I need for the .net 4 framework and Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0 to be deployed with the app.  I have the check box checked to "Create setup program to install prerequisite componets."  I also have the Microsoft .net Framework 4 (x86 and x64) checked and the Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks 10.0 checked.  the Download prerequisites from teh component vendor's web site is also selected.  The publish says it's successful, but when i run the application, it tells me that i need the .net 4 framework installed and an ok button.  click the ok button and i'm done.  it doesn't provide a link, doesn't launch anything... nothing.  From the googing i've done this is the way i'm suppose to have it setup.  Can anyone give me some pointers as to what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks
shannon

Comment: Have you tried running the setup.exe that is created with the ClickOnce. I thnk there is normally a link to it on the bottom of the ClickOnce web page

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add Prerequisites in the same published location. And select download Prerequisites from the same location option button in Prerequisites segment. When you publish build the application, All Prerequisites related folders will be created under the folder you have published the application. This will help you to copy and paste entire folder structure onto live server for deployment. This has to be done for the first time. For the later releases you only have to copy and paste application related files. Of course, If you change any of the Prerequisites then you have to copy them onto live server also.